# Keeping state of button on closing application wpf vs2012

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have some buttons on a Windows, when i Click on button it disables ,but when I restart program after closing  it becomes enabled again, Is there any way to remember state of button whether it is enabled or disbaled ? I am using VS2012 Ultimate

Application is in  C# WPF .net4.5

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

You ll find out  the button by using following code:

IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""));

After getting the button u can check the state of the button by using

bool buttonEnabled = element.Enabled;

Comment: This won't work if the program got restarted....Actually this doesn't solve anything OP asked.

Comment: i know state of button i disabled it, I want program to remember it when it restarts

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to persist your settings. Use either a database or a config/text file, depending on your needs.

Comment: is there not any option in WPF to remember states of its control

Comment: @user1831591, not when the app itself is shutdown.. How would it do that?